# Prove inequality $\frac{a_1a_2...a_n}{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^n}\le \frac{(1-a_1)(1-a_2)...(1-a_n)}{(n-a_1-a_2-...-a_n)^n}$

Tags: inequality, induction

> Let $n\in \mathbb N, a_1,a_2, ...,a_n\in \left(0,\frac 12 \right]$. Prove inequality:
>   $$\frac{a_1a_2...a_n}{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^n}\le \frac{(1-a_1)(1-a_2)...(1-a_n)}{(n-a_1-a_2-...-a_n)^n}$$

**My work so far:**

By induction:

If $n=2$ then $$\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2}\le \frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{(2-a-b)^2} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow4ab-4ab(a+b)+ab(a+b)^2\le ab(a+b)^2-(a+b)^3+(a+b)^2 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow(1-a-b)(a-b)^2 \ge0 -$$obviously, becouse  $a,b\in \left(0,\frac 12 \right]$.

Comment: Why didn't you continue your induction proof?

Comment: @YuriyS: I can not do the induction step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $$f(x) = \log\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$$ is concave on $(0,\tfrac12]$ (since $f''\leq 0$ on that interval) so by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) $$\frac{f(a_1)+\ldots+f(a_n)}{n}\leq f\left(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}n\right).$$ Your inequality is an immediate consequence of this.